# Linking the implementation of the query with time

Tags: php

I want to execute a query with time

**here my code**

```
if (isset($_GET[$this->appConfig['system']['installkey']])){
require_once( MODEL_PATH . 'install.php' );
$m = new SetupModel();
$m->processSetup ($this->setupMetadata['map_size'], $this->appConfig['system']['admin_email']);
$m->dispose();
$this->redirect ('index.php');
return;
}
```

This SQL query I want the specified timeframe
For instance:
15:07:00
Hours: minutes: seconds
When time runs are executed code link above

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Please elaborate.  And, tag it with the correct tags.  SQL would not appear to be related to the code you are using.

Comment: iam edit my Question sorry for bad english

Comment: check about cron jobs (scheduled jobs) in linux os.

Comment: Has verified that can not be implemented through

Answer (score 0):

You should check about [crons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

If you don't have a dedicated server or a cron management, you can use something like WebCron to automatically call a webpage each time a day.

Anyway, it needs to be external, you can't do that only with PHP, something has to trigger it.

Comment: I want anything else fueled with any time that the page contains a lot of it and I want to be igniting each one with a time limit in addition to that it does not accept cron Jobs